# Laravel page not found error while using global route prefix

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to build multilingual website with laravel and I want to make urls seo friendly.

So I added language prefix to whole routes using `RouteServiceProvider`

```
Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => $this->app->getLocale()
        ], function ($router) {...);
```

Are we should any parameter for the language ? Because I didin't use any parameter for routes..

```
Route::group(["prefix"=>trans("routes.admin")],function (){
    Route::get("/",["as"=>"admin.index","uses"=>"AdminController@index"]);
});
```

I research about it on stackoverflow, laravel.com but I couldn't find anything useful.

How do I can fix this error ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$this->app->getLocale() return string, try this:

```
Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => '{locale?}'
    ], function ($router) {
             $router->get("admin",["as"=>"admin.index","uses"=>"AdminController@index"]);
        });
```

Comment: just an ordinary 404 error.Also I checked out the laravel.log, there is no log about this.

Comment: app.test/en/admin

Comment: dude it's RouteServiceProdiver class

Comment: put `Route::get("admin",["as"=>"admin.index","uses"=>"AdminController@index"]);` in your route file, what is the problem
?